# Function to check the number of possible words that can be made up from another word (Python 3.6)

Tags: python, python-3.6

So there is this assignment I have been set where I have to make a program where I input a 9 letter word and then try to input all the possible words that can be made from the letters of the word originally input. The possible words are only valid if they match up with the words contained within a given text file (which has been converted into the list of words wordsList in the program), among other things which are not relevant here. I have had no problem with this up until this specific task: "The total number of possible correct answers is counted and displayed". The total number of possible correct words that can be made up from the letters of the original word needs to be displayed right after the original word is inputted so the user knows what they are aiming for. However, I have had some problems with this. I have attempted to accomplish this task with the following function:

```
def totalPossible(masterWord):
    total = 0
    answers = []
    for word in wordsList:

        if word[:-1] in masterWord:
        total += 1
        answers.append(word[:-1])

    #The [:-1] is there because there is a \n at the end of every word in the wordsList

    return total
```

The function only works if the entire word with every letter in order is present in masterWord, not if the individual letters making up every word in wordsList are present in masterWord, which is what I believe needs to be done. For example, if the original word, masterWord, is 'ADDICTION', my function as it is will recognise two "words" within wordsList which are 'ADDICTION' itself and 'TION' (don't ask me why) and will increment the total and append the answers list accordingly, but will not recognise something like 'COAT', which is a valid answer and is also present within wordsList but is not detected as a possible answer by my function. So, how do I make this code check the individual letters of every word within wordsList against masterWord, so as to find out if each word in wordsList is a word that can be made from the letters in masterWord, and then increment the total counter every time a word in wordsList is found to be made from the letters in masterWord. P.S. masterWord is just a string meant to represent 1 nine letter word.

Example of output:
Enter word (masterWord): [word here]

There are x(this is total) possible words that can be made from that word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are testing whether `'coat'` is in `'addiction'`. While the letters in `'coat'` are indeed also in `'addiction'`, they do not appear in order, and so your test returns `False`. Instead, you need to see if all the letters appearing in `'coat'` also appear in `'addiction'`, *regardless of order*. See below for an example that ought to get you going.

```
# first, properly import your word list to get rid of whitespace
# in each word (i.e. the \n character). Something like:

wordsList = []

with open('wordList.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        word = line.strip()
        if word:
            wordsList.append(word)
            # may want to modify case of letters in word as well
            # if so, see word.upper() or word.lower()

# then you need to confirm each letter of each word appears in masterWord
# Something like:

def totalPossible(masterWord):

    total = 0
    answers = []

    for word in wordsList:
        in_total = 0
        for char in word:
            if char in masterWord: # case must match
                in_total += 1
        if in_total == len(word):
            total += 1
            answers.append(word)

    return total, answers # also return your answer list
```

Comment: Thank you for this. It works just fine. I have just one more question, though. Below "for line in file:",  "if word:" isn't necessary, is it? I deleted it as I thought that
    word = line.strip(), then on the next line,
    wordsList.append(word)
Does the same thing without the "if word:". Am I correct in thinking this?

Comment: Not strictly necessary, no. However, when importing .txt files, the end-of-file is often on its own blank line. After stripping this last blank line of its whitespace, it becomes None. Without the if statement, you would store a None object in the last position of your array, which can cause abnormal things to happen later if you’re not aware of this.

Answer (score 0):

The `Counter` class is a nice tool for this sort of problem:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> word_list = ["coat", "add", "zebra", "foo"]
>>> def possible_words(master_word):
...     master = Counter(master_word)
...     return [
...         word for word in word_list
...         if all(master.get(c, 0) >= Counter(word)[c] for c in word)
...     ]
...
>>> possible_words("addiction")
['coat', 'add']
>>> len(total_possible("addiction"))
2
```

Comment: This is useful. However I accepted jacobs answer because it avoids the use of imports, which in my situation would be more suitable as I was set the assignment with the presupposition that I wouldn't use, shall we say, unsanctioned imports.